# Sodium hydride 60% dispersion in mineral oil

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

I've got a bottle of sodium hydride 60% dispersion in mineral oil. It's not "in mineral oil" it's just powder with an oil coating. I'm using it in an inert reaction, is there a way to remove the oil?

Answer (score 2):

Place your weighed sodium hydride dispersion in the reaction flask. Swirl with hexane/heptane, let it settle, pipette off the clear solvent. Repeat then add your reaction solvent. The mineral oil is inert and will not interfere with your reaction and runs at the top of a tlc/column. Most of the time it is not necessary to remove it.